# how to cast date in laravel model?

Tags: laravel, datetime, casting, format

I want to cast some field with date format.
But only created_at and updated_at is formated with correctly.
The invoice_date and due_date still not correct.

```
^ array:17 [▼
  "id" => "1"
  "vendor_id" => "12"
  "invoice_number" => "INV-1111"
  "invoice_date" => "2022-10-09 00:00:00"    <----
  "due_date" => "2022-11-08 01:52:21"     <-----
  "order_id" => "1"
  "total" => "125"
  "created_at" => "09-Oct-2022 02:10:03"    <-----
  "updated_at" => "09-Oct-2022 02:10:03"    <-----
  "invoicedetails" => array:1 [▶]
  "number_of_items" => "1"
```

At Model file :

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d-M-Y H:m:s',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:d-M-Y H:m:s',
    'invoice_date' => 'date:d-M-Y',
    'duedate' => 'date:d-M-Y',
];
```

At migration file :

```
    $table->string('invoice_number');
    $table->date('invoice_date');
    $table->date('due_date');
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you can cast date in laravel model as:

```
protected $casts = [
  'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

for more visit [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

for custom casting you can use accenssor feature. For laravel 9 use this:

```
protected function invoiceDate(): Attribute
  {
      return Attribute::make(
       get: fn ($value) => Carbon::parse($value)->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A'),
   );
}
```

for more view [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)